# Implement a 2 dimensional array of months and dates in React native

Tags: react-native, multidimensional-array

I would like to implement an 2d array(later i will push it into Firebase db) of months(By names) and dates(like - 01/01/2020)

The goal is that in firebase it will look like something like this:
Doc for every month(Jan,Feb etc...)
Inside every doc: the dates of the some month (1/1/20,2/1/20 and etc)

Array of months:

```
const months = new Array(11);
months[0] = "Jan";
months[1] = "Feb";
months[2] = "Mar";
months[3] = "Apr";
months[4] = "May";
months[5] = "Jun";
months[6] = "Jul";
months[7] = "Aug";
months[8] = "Sep";
months[9] = "Oct";
months[10] = "Nov";
months[11] = "Dec";
```

Code of the Dates push(its pushing all 365 dates into the array):

```
    const dates = [];
for (
  firstDay;
  firstDay < lastDay;
  firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 1)
) {
  dates.push(new Date(firstDay));
}
```

How can i implement what i want using the following code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, months should be an array of strings (as your first piece of code shows) or an array of arrays (of numbers.. the days..).

It can't be both.

Since you want 2d array you probably looking for the second option and then the strings ("Jan", "Feb", etc..) have no meaning.

To implement 2d array you can do something like this:

```
const daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, ...];
const array2d = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
     const days = [];
     for (let j = 0; j < daysInMonth[i]; j++) {
          days.push(j);
     }
     array2d.push(days);
}
```

If you want to implement the first option, with the strings (which I assume you don't as you 2d array for firebas..), then you can do it with objects:

```
   {
      Jan: [0,1,2,...31],
      Feb: [0,1,2,...28],
      ...
   }
```

Comment: If im getting you correctly, you mean i should replace my 1st code segment with
Jan: []
Feb: []
and then implement the 2nd array as you suggested?

Comment: Hey, i tried to mix up your answer with my code and its adding only the first month, its seems to ignore the i++

Comment: You sure that the condition is `i<12` and not `1<1`?

Comment: I need to push every month days into his place
Meaning:
Jan will have 31 numbers
Feb will have 28 numbers
and etc

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly